# Set a range on greater/less than or equal to

Tags: python

```
score = int(input("Enter score: ")
if score >= 90:
grade = "A"
if score >= 80:
grade = "B"
print(grade)
```

when I run the program and enter a score of anything 80 or higher, the grade will be a "B" because score >= 80.

I was expecting a score of 95 to be an A and not a B. Is there a way I can set the range of the <= int he code here?

Comment: Your missing a parentheses and are using an invalid quotation mark character. Did you type this in a word processor (i.e. MS Word, google Docs)?

Comment: You have a) a missing `)` b) bad indentation and c) an `if` where there should be an `elif` and d) a missing value for `grade` if no condition matches.

Comment: The second `if` should be an `elif`

Comment: ohh i see now, it was the elif i was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(note, that in the snippet you are missing indentations, this post assumes they are correct)

The result is "B", because the last `if` is satisfied. (because 95 is greater than 80) What you probably wanted is to use an else if block: `elif`. So the new code would be:

```py
score = int(input("Enter score: "))
if score >= 90:
  grade = "A"
elif score >= 80:
  grade = “B”
print(grade)
```

This would output `A` for values greater or equal to 90, `B` for values greater than or equal to 80 and smaller than 90. And crash for anything else. The `elif` block only runs if the previous `ìf` is false.

Comment: Why would this print "ERROR"?

Comment: The code wouldn't actually print "ERROR", but normally fail with a stacktrace. I've corrected the post to me more clear

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `if` condition only and not `elif` so initially it checks the score is greater than or equal to 90 and stores the grade as 'A' then it checks score is greater than or equal to 80 and overwrites grade = 'B' That is the problem so use `elif`. Please check the below code.

```py
score = int(input("Enter score: "))
if score >= 90:
    grade = "A"
elif score >= 80:
    grade = “B”
print(grade)
```

You can try the match case also.

```
score = int(input("Enter score: "))

match score:
    case _ if score >= 90:
        print('A')
    case _ if score >= 80:
        print('B')
    case _:
        print('Sorry')
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is a critical part of Python syntax.

Even with corrected indentation, your code would fail with a NameError exception if the input value was less than 80.

You should **always** validate user input. Don't just assume that the input can be converted (in this case) to int.

```
while True:
    try:
        score = int(input('Enter score: '))
        if score >= 90:
            grade = 'A'
        elif score >= 80:
            grade = 'B'
        else:
            grade = '?' # default for lower values
        print(grade)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input')
```

Answer (score -1):

**Fix up your code, then change the second `if` to an `elif`:**

1. Change the line `score = int(input("Enter score: ")` to `score = int(input("Enter score: "))`, adding that closing parentheses.
2. Indent after the `if` statements! You're code won't work otherwise.
3. Change `if score >= 80:` to `elif score >= 80:`. Right now, it matches the first `if` statement, setting the `score` to `"A"`. But then it goes to the next `if` statement, which also matches, setting `score` to `"B"`. Changing to `elif` skips the `elif` if the `if` matches.

Fixed code:

```
score = int(input("Enter score: "))
if score >= 90:
    grade = "A"
elif score >= 80:
    grade = "B"
print(grade)
```

Output:

```
Enter score: 95
A
```

Comment: What will happen if the input cannot be converted to int? What if it can be converted to int but is less than 80?

Comment: @DarkKnight, I'm not writing their code for them, I'm merely fixing the issues they're currently experiencing. What if they want do want it to raise an error if the input can't be converted to an int? What if they want to raise a NameError if it's below 80? This isn't code review.

Comment: I appreciate that you don't want to write their code in full but posting code that is flawed is unhelpful